# Browsers silently adding trusted root certificates in Windows

Tags: windows, web-browser, certificate-authority

When accessing https://internetbanking.caixa.gov.br (site of a well known bank in Brazil), the server returns a certificate signed by *"Autoridade Certificadora Raiz Brasileira"* (*Brazilian Root Certification Authority*). This certificate is not in Window's list of trusted certificates before the access, but **it appears there after the access**.

Here's the exact steps (tested in Windows XP and 8 with IExplorer and Google Chrome):

- Open `Control Panel -> Internet Options -> Content -> Certificates`
- Verify there is no *"Autoridade Certificadora Raiz Brasileira"* in the list of trusted root or intermediate cerficiates.
- Close the open windows
- Access https://internetbanking.caixa.gov.br
- Verify no warnings, alerts or confirmations appeared (with green padlock nonetheless).
- Open `Control Panel -> Internet Options -> Content -> Certificates` again
- Verify the *"Autoridade Certificadora Raiz Brasileira"* certificate appeared in the `Trusted Root Certification Authorities` tab.

How did that happen? Is there a mechanism that allows a user application to force the OS to trust new **root** certificates without alerts or confirmations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In the default configuration for Windows XP with Service Pack 2 (SP2),
>   if a user removes one of the trusted root certificates, and the
>   certifier who issued that root certificate is trusted by Microsoft,
>   Windows will silently add the root certificate back into the user's
>   store and use the original trust settings

I guess if you didn't remove it yourself, you can add to the above, " if a trusted root certificate is missing, Windows XP will silently add it.

via http://www.proper.com/root-cert-problem/

Comment: The cert is not present in a clean installation, so it's not an issue of being added back. But the site you linked mention an alternative way, which could be the answer: `when you try to validate a certificate that chains to a certification authority that is trusted by Microsoft but it is not in your root store, Windows Vista will silently add that certification authority`. Doesn't explain the behavior in the Windows XP machine, but it's a start.

Comment: @BoppreH: Microsoft regularly releases updates to the root certificates through Windows Update: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=38918

Comment: Thanks @cmorse, but this doesn't explain why the certificate only appears the moment the website is visited.