# How can I list all self-signed certificates in my stores on a Windows client?

Tags: certificates, windows, powershell, automation

I'm on a mission to list the self-signed certificates ('*issued by*' and '*issued to*' match) on my machine via an automated method. PowerShell is available for use. Preferably the results would be exported to a nice human-readable file.

Comment: Only way I know how to do it would be through [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa382363(v=vs.85).aspx).  But maybe checkout this link on [browsing certificates with PowerShell](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/scotts-it-blog/2014/12/30/working-with-certificates-in-powershell/)

Comment: If relevant note the roots in the Windows store on [your] machine are **not the only ones that will be *trusted*** by most software on your Windows system e.g. IE/Edge Chrome and dotNET, but not Firefox and Java.

Comment: What RoraZ and Dave said. Also: the Windows cert stores are really more of a CACHE than an actual store proper. Windows trusts about 300 roots out of the box. And the local store/cache is updated via the Internet ON-DEMAND if you ever encounter one of them. See [1](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/46332/browsers-silently-adding-trusted-root-certificates-in-windows), [2](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/108951/how-much-of-a-problem-is-it-that-windows-hides-some-of-the-trusted-root-ca-cer).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Try “cert:” PsDrive

This here will be human readable. And (thanks to the semicolon as the delimiter) it will also open nicely in Excel:

```
dir cert: -Recurse | 
where {$_.subject -ne $null} | 
where {$_.subject -eq $_.issuer} | 
Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8 -delimiter ';' -path selfsignedcerts.csv
```

#### Further reading

- Great blog on this: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/scotts-it-blog/2014/12/30/working-with-certificates-in-powershell/

Comment: What am I doing wrong?  Powershell is rejecting this.

Comment: @Loren: open a dedicated question for that and then give the the link.