# TrustCor root CA not in Windows 10

Tags: tls, certificate-authority

Just saw a piece of news about potential issues with TrustCor root CA.

I don't see the TrustCor root CA in windows certificate manager.

I do see it in Firefox cert store.

Browsing to [trustcor.com](https://trustcor.com) in Chrome under Windows 10 works fine showing a padlock icon.

Viewing the site's cert shows this at the root: TrustCor RootCert CA-2

AFAIK, Chrome uses Windows cert store but again that root CA doesn't seem to be there.

How's this site trusted by Chrome? Possible cross signing?

Comment: BTW, one should note that that CA is super dodgy https://twitter.com/matthew_d_green/status/1589985955725062144?t=gVLK7By0BeBy4I14eWyckg&s=19

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chrome uses the system certificates under Windows, but also a select few others, list at https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/main/net/data/ssl/chrome_root_store/root_store.md

[Chromium Root CA policy](https://www.chromium.org/Home/chromium-security/root-ca-policy/) explains it all.

TrustCor is one of them, no shenanigans here.

December 2022 edit : Trustcor was in fact very shady and is getting removed from some trust stores, possibly more later : https://groups.google.com/a/mozilla.org/g/dev-security-policy/c/oxX69KFvsm4/m/WJXUELicBQAJ

Comment: Thanks. I see it now. Here's what happened in case others run into this. 100% sure it wasn't in the list when I pulled up Windows certificate manager. eventually I right clicked on "Trusted Root Certification Authorities" and selected Find and searched for "trustcor" and it found them. Now they appear in the list. Don't know if it was a cache issue or what.

Comment: rvh: non-ancient Windows _automatically adds_ root certs on Microsoft's trust list, see https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/46332/browsers-silently-adding-trusted-root-certificates-in-windows  https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/108951/how-much-of-a-problem-is-it-that-windows-hides-some-of-the-trusted-root-ca-cer https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/81491/are-there-other-roots-of-trust-on-my-computer-aside-from-these-46-root-certifica